# Use each line of file as part of regex

Tags: terminal, grep, pipe

I have a file with a simple string on each line...

```
bob
fred
sally
```

I want to use each string as part of a regex

```
grep -r "regex using <bob>" (value from line 1)
grep -r "regex using <fred>" (value from line 2
grep -r "regex using <sally>" (value from line 3)
```

I expect to use the file strings in various regex's so not wanting to edit original file. Preferably just using pipes, or creating a temp file if that's a must.

Comment: Using each line in a regex OR statement would also work for me, eg. [bob|sally|fred]

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want. Do you want to convert your file to regex like `bob|sally|fred`?

Comment: I want to convert to a grep that find instances of <bob|sally|fred><space><quoted string>, or some similar expression.

Comment: Add to your question example of data in which you want to search, and mark what segments are expected to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*/regex using <&>/' file-with-strings | grep -f- file-to-search
```

Basically use sed to wrap each line of file-with-strings in your regex, then pipe it to `grep -f-` which will read regexes from stdin

Or:

```
grep -P "regex using <$(tr '\n' '|' file-with-strings)>" file-to-search
```

... which will do what you want in the comments: assemble `bob|fred|sally` and wrap it in your regex.  Requires bash or similar for `$()` syntax.